# How to find deg 4 and deg 5 irreducible polynomials over $\mathbb{F}_3$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials

> Give examples of irreducible polynomials $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ in $\mathbb{F}_3[x]$ such that $\deg f(x)=4$ and $\deg g(x)=5$.

I can find irreducible polynomials of degree $2$ or $3$ by taking such polynomials which has no zeros in $\mathbb{F}_3$. But for $\deg 4$ and $\deg 5$ I don't know how to find a polynomial and then show that it will be irreducible.

Please suggest me any tips.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A polynomial of degree $4$ or $5$ is irreducible if it has no linear or quadratic factor. There aren't many linear and quadratic polynomials over $\Bbb{F}_3$, so list them all and then just pick polynomials of degrees $4$ and $5$ that isn't divisible by any of them.

Of course you only need to consider *monic* polynomials. There are precisely $3$ linear monic polynomials over $\Bbb{F}_3$, and $9$ quadratic monic polynomials over $\Bbb{F}_3$, and only $3$ of them are irreducible. So there are only $9$ irreducible factors to avoid.

---

Alternatively you could take a more abstract approach, which may seem like magic if you aren't already very familiar with this topic:

Because $\Bbb{F}_3$ contains no primitive fifth root of unity, the fifth cyclotomic polynomial
$$\Phi_5=x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$$
is irreducible over $\Bbb{F}_3$.

A similar trick works for degree $5$; there is of course no cyclotomic polynomial of degree $5$, but because $\Bbb{F}_3$ has no primitive eleventh root of unity, the eleventh cyclotomic polynomial $\Phi_{11}$ is irreducible over $\Bbb{F}_3$. Then for any root $\zeta$ of $\Phi_{11}$ the minimal polynomial of $\zeta+\zeta^{-1}$ is irreducible of degree $5$, and the minimial polynomial is
$$x^5+x^4-4x^3-3x^2+3x+1.$$

Comment: How about $x^4$+x+1 and $x^5$+1? Am I getting this right?

Comment: What makes you think those are irreducible? Have you checked them for linear and quadratic factors?

Comment: @Sunit das Your second example is bad. There is a factor $x+1$

Comment: The first example also fails, because $x=1$ is a root.

Comment: Ok i will try to understand  this first. And I will provide a examples in comments. Sorry for my previous examples.

Comment: I think, $x^5+x^4+x+2$ is irreducible, which gives also $x^5+2x^4+2x+2$

Comment: @servaes. In in the last polynomial since we are doing all work in $\mathbb{Z_3}$ so the polynomial is $x^5$+$x^4$-$x^3$+1 right?

Comment: @Sunitdas Yes, that's right. Conceptually I'm doing all the arithmetic in $\Bbb{Z}[x]$, knowing that the result will remain irreducible in $\Bbb{F}_3[x]$.

Comment: Your examples work, but your logic is faulty. $\Bbb{F}_5$ has no eighth roots of unity, but $\Phi_8(x)=x^4+1$ is not irreducible over $\Bbb{F}_5$:
$$x^4+1=x^4-4=(x^2-2)(x^2+2).$$ 
The correct condition is that if $p\nmid n$ then $\Phi_n(x)$ is irreducible over $\Bbb{F}_p$ if and only if  the smallest positive integer such that $n\mid p^m-1$ is equal to $\phi(n)$. Observe that by Euler we always have $p^{\phi(n)}\equiv1\pmod n$. So for example because $5$ isn't a factor of either $3-1$ or $3^2-1$ it follows that $\Phi_5(x)$ is irreducible over $\Bbb{F}_3$.

Comment: In fact $\Phi_8(x)$ is reducible modulo every prime, because $8\mid p^2-1$ for all odd integers $p$.